# Converting shapefile latitude to real one

Tags: python, shapefile

I have a list of geocoords (lat, long) and a shapefile with different layers. I want to be able to identify to which layer belongs each coord.

But the shapefile (.shp) has poligons in which the latitude and longitude are expressed in numbers within a weird range, such as 120724.86008864 and 484497.34058312

I know the prj file contains the information about how this transformation was made, but I don't seem to get how. This is it:

PROJCS["RD_New",GEOGCS["GCS_Amersfoort",DATUM["D_Amersfoort",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",155000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",463000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",5.38763888888889],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999079],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",52.15616055555555],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Concrete question is how to transform a regular lat/long point into those of the shapefile.

Working in Python, with this library http://gdal.org/python/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want get coordinates? Or parse prj file?

Comment: I can parse the file with no problems, but the lat/long in the shapefile are in a different scale or range. Eg, a latitude of 120724.86008864 which is obviously wrong. I have normal latitudes such as 52.3605883. So I want to know which transformation I have to apply to my normal coordinates in order to be like those of the file. Then I will be able to intersect them with the poligons in the layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# define input
shape_file = "file.shp"
o_lat = 52.3605883
o_lon = 4.8593157

# geospatial bureocracy
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
shape = driver.Open(shape_file)
layer = shape.GetLayer()
geo_ref = layer.GetSpatialRef()
point_ref = ogr.osr.SpatialReference()
point_ref.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
ctran = ogr.osr.CoordinateTransformation(point_ref, geo_ref)

# critical part: transform longitude/latitude to the shapefile's projection
[t_lon, t_lat, z] = ctran.TransformPoint(o_lon, o_lat)
print('original coords', o_lon, o_lat)
print('transformed coords', t_lon, t_lat)

# create the needle
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.SetPoint_2D(0, t_lon, t_lat)
layer.SetSpatialFilter(point)

# look it up
for feature in layer:
    polygon = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    if polygon.Contains(point):
        print('Found it', feature.ExportToJson()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        import re
        regex = "\d{1,3}\.\d+"
        s ="""PROJCS["RD_New",GEOGCS["GCS_Amersfoort",DATUM["D_Amersfoort",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",155000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",463000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",5.38763888888889],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999079],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",52.15616055555555],UNIT["Meter",1]] """

        m = re.search(regex, s)

        if m:
            print m.groups()
```

Comment: What's your intent?

Comment: I want get all decimal with max 3 digits after decimal point from string. ex:
12.55
3.44
321.11